# Is this code well defined (Casting HANDLE)

Tags: c

There's many instances of code similar to this in the codebase I'm working in these days. This is a thin C wrapper aroundthe OS API.

```
// From the OS
HANDLE CreateObject();
void CloseHandle(HANDLE);

typedef struct tagFOO {} FOO;

FOO* Foo_New()
{
    return (FOO*)CreateObject();
}

void Foo_Delete(FOO* foo)
{
    if(foo != NULL)
    {
        CloseHandle((HANDLE)foo);
    }
}

void Foo_Bar(FOO* foo)
{
    if(foo != NULL)
    {
        HANDLE h = (HANDLE)foo;
        // Do something interesting with h
    }
}
```

This seems to work and I want to avoid touching it if I can, but is this well defined? It seems very fishy to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C99 standard says:

> #### 6.7.2.1 Structure and union specifiers
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> struct-or-union-specifier:
>        struct-or-union identifieropt { struct-declaration-list }
>        struct-or-union identifier
> struct-or-union:
>        struct
>        union
> struct-declaration-list:
>        struct-declaration
>        struct-declaration-list struct-declaration
> ```

Officially, that precludes your empty structure definition (and so does §6.5.2.1 in the C89 standard); there should be at least one member in the structure.  However, you have to push GCC fairly hard to get it to complain; I used `-std=c99 -pedantic` and only with the `-pedantic` did it warn 'struct has no members'.

In my view, you would be better off (more strictly portable) with:

```
typedef struct tagFOO FOO;
```

Or, even using:

```
typedef struct FOO FOO;
```

Comment: Won't this only declare the struct and not define it? Would it be possible to cast to/from this struct that wasn't defined?

Comment: @Flame: yes, it only declares the struct.  But you're only using pointers to it, not actually storing anything in it (because there are no members in it, you cannot store anything), so you are no worse off than you were before.  And you are better off to the extent that a C compiler can legitimately reject the code with an empty structure, even though the empirical evidence is that some compilers do in fact accept them.

Comment: That `typedef` doesn't even declare the struct; it only creates an _alias_ to the type. If the type wasn't declared beforehand then the typedef won't compile.

Comment: @wilhelmtell: please go try it - it will compile.  Then go and look up forward declarations and incomplete types.  You can write: `typedef struct WhatNot WhatNot; struct WhatNot { WhatNot *next; WhatNot *prev; void *data; };` and it is completely OK.  You can omit the second statement and, as long as you only use pointers, it is also OK.  Obviously, you can't dereference the pointers - that requires the data structure to be complete.

Answer (score 2):

The intent of the HANDLE definition is to be an opaque type, one that you can't make any assumptions about. In practice we know it's a pointer, and because of Windows famed backwards compatibility this is unlikely to ever change.

This does have a huge code smell, and if you have half an excuse I'd refactor it. But I don't think you're taking a huge risk if you leave it alone.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case: `HANDLE` is actually a 64-bit integer value, `FOO*` is a 32-bit pointer. Casting loses information, and checking `foo != NULL` is wrong (because it could be a valid value for the handle).

This is indeed very fishy.